# Minimum Initial Velocity to Pass over two Walls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

A stone is to be projected from ground level over two walls which are a distance of d meters apart. Both walls have a height of h meters. Let $ g = 9.8 m/s^2 $. Find the minimum intial velocity of the stone such that is passes over both walls (Assume no air resistance).

I let the origin O be the point of projection and the distance from O to the first wall be c meters away hence making the second wall $ (c+d) $ meters from the origin. I started by finding the position vector of the ball $\vec r$ at time $t$ by starting with; $$ \frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}= \begin{pmatrix}0\\ -g \end{pmatrix} $$ Then integrating with respect to time up to position giving; $$\vec r = \begin{pmatrix} utcos(\theta) \\ utsin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}gt^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Note it was assumed that at $t=0$ $\frac{dr}{dt} = \begin{pmatrix} ucos(\theta) \\ usin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} $ where u is the initial velocity and $\theta$ is the angle of projection. It was also assumed that at $t=0$ $\vec r = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. I'm assuming the minimum intial velocity is the velocity which results in the projectile just barely passing over the two buildings. From this we can say that $\vec r$ passes through $(c,d)$ and $(c+d,h)$ at times $t_1$ and $t_2$ respectively. This gives the system of equations; $$ c=ut_1cos(\theta)...(1) $$ $$ c+d=ut_2cos(\theta)...(2)$$ $$ h=ut_1sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}gt_1^2...(3)$$ $$ h = ut_2sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}gt_2^2...(4)$$ This is where I am stuck. From these we need $c,u,t_1,t_2$ and $\theta$ all in terms of $d,g,h$ but how can we acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the origin as the top of the first wall.  The minimum speed needed to just get over the second wall is from the range formula $$d = \frac{v^2}{g}$$ and it should be moving at 45 degrees to the horizontal at the new origin.

Then doing an equation of motion vertically, you can get $v_{y0}$, the initial vertical speed from the ground, and similarly you can find $v_{x0}$, that's the same as at the new origin.

All the best with it, the answer seems to be

$$v_{y0} = \sqrt{\frac{dg}{2} +2gh}$$

$$v_{x0} = \sqrt{\frac{dg}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response. Everything makes sense to me except how do we know that the stone will be at an angle of 45 degrees at the new origin on the top of the first wall?

Comment: @ Swiss Gnome Glad it makes sense...that angle gives the minimum velocity for it to go a distance $d$, to do with the range formula $R = v^2 \sin 2 \theta /g$ all the best